# Prove the set of positive even integers is well-ordered using the well-ordering principle?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I'm a beginner. According to my professor, I must write out every step as clearly as possible.

**Question: Prove the set of positive even integers is well-ordered using the well-ordering principle.**

**Solution (According to Bartelby.com):** By definition, the set of positive even integers is the subset of positive integers. Moreover, since the even integers are well-ordered, (by the well-ordering principle), the positive even integers are well-ordered.

**However, I'm unable to understand the proof. How do we know that if a set has the property then its subset has the property? (My Professor demands I rely on proofs rather than intuition).**

Below is my attempt at the problem:

---

**My attempt:** By definition, the set of positive even integers is the subset of positive even integers. Hence if the set of positive even integers are well-ordered, then; the set of postive integers are well-ordered. Despite this, we must prove if positive integers are well-ordered then positive even integers *are well-ordered*. Therefore, we take the contrapositive.

If the positive integers are not well-ordered then the positive even integers are not well-ordered; however, the positive integers are well-ordered (by the well-ordering principle). This is a contradiction to our hypothesis where the positive integers are not well-ordered. Hence if the positive integers are well-ordered then the positive even integers are well-ordered. Therefore, the positive even integers are well-ordered.

**Question: Am I correct or have I made a mistake in my steps? Try and explain step by step?**

Comment: The even integers aren't well-ordered according to the usual ordering.  Of course, any set can be well-ordered, but the question isn't worth asking if one is allowed to use this.  The solution you found on the Web seems wrong to me.  I don't understand your solution.  Why is it true that if the positive even integers are well-ordered then so it the set of positive integers?  Also, the first sentence of your proof must have an extra "positive" in it.

Comment: @saulspatz What do you mean? Any subset of a well-ordered set is well ordered, so the web solution is fine (if lacking this proof).  $\quad$ I agree that OP's solution doesn't make sense, and might have screwed up the contrapositive parts.

Comment: @CalvinLin The web solution says that the even integers are well-ordered.  What is the smallest even integer?  Of course, now that I think of it, the OP may have miscopied it.

Comment: @saulspatz Is this better?

Comment: @Arbuja You don't seem to understand my comment.  I am talking about the solution from Bartleby.com.  ASs quoted by you, it says, "since the even integers are well-ordered ..., " but the even integers are *not* well-ordered.  There is no smallest even integer. Consider the even integers$-2,-4,-6,\cdots$  Perhaps Bartleby actually said that the positive integers are well-ordered, and you misquoted them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the definition of a well ordered set to prove that any subset of a well ordered set is well ordered.  A well ordered set is one that any subset has a smallest element.  If you take a subset of a well ordered set, all of its subsets are subsets of the larger set, so they have a smallest element.  This shows the subset is well ordered.